# Webservice timeout java web service

Tags: java, web-services, service, timeout

I have a webservice stub. I am setting the timeout for the stub like this.
stub.*getServiceClient().getOptions().setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(timeout* * 1 * 1000);

But this doesnt work (i.e. the connection is alive even after the timeout period). Can you please tell me why is it so?
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

We implement the timeout for our webservice clients as follows

```
org.apache.axis2.client.Options options = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
options.setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(timeoutMillisLimit + 2500); 
stub._getServiceClient().setOptions(options);
```

Get the Options object, set the values, then set the Options object back on the stub,

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is the timeout period for a request coming into the WS...ie after 30 seconds give up if you can't return.